# Converting string to int in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table tblcatalogue and there is a column classid with datatype varchar.I want a result set containing orderby classid ,but the problem is using order by classid is not giving the desired result.so i tried to convert classid to integer like

```
var query= itemRepository.GetAll();  
results = query.ToList().OrderBy(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.ClassId));
```

but I am getting sql query like

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[SubjectId] AS [SubjectId], 
[Extent1].[SeriesId] AS [SeriesId], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
[Extent1].[ISBN] AS [ISBN], 
[Extent1].[Edition] AS [Edition], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[Discount] AS [Discount], 
[Extent1].[BoardId] AS [BoardId], 
[Extent1].[ClassId] AS [ClassId]
FROM [dbo].[tblCataLogue] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[ClassId] ASC
```

I wanted converted sql query like

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[SubjectId] AS [SubjectId], 
[Extent1].[SeriesId] AS [SeriesId], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
[Extent1].[ISBN] AS [ISBN], 
[Extent1].[Edition] AS [Edition], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[Discount] AS [Discount], 
[Extent1].[BoardId] AS [BoardId], 
[Extent1].[ClassId] AS [ClassId]
FROM [dbo].[tblCataLogue] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY covnert(int,[Extent1].[ClassId]) ASC
```

Because it is giving the right result set

Comment: Remove `ToList()`

Comment: I am getting error like LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2):

When using `ToList()` you are executing the query to the database and therefore the ordering you want does not take place. Remove `ToList()` and the order by clause will also be translated to sql:

```
results = query.OrderBy(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.ClassId)).ToList();
```

---

As for the proceeding error, the `Convert.ToInt32` is not supported by the linq provider and cannot be translated to sql. Therefore you should do one of two things:

1. As at the beginning, first retrieve the data to in memory (using `ToList()`/`AsEnumerable()`) and then convert
2. Change the column in the database to be of type int - IMO as your data is a number it should in any case be represented as such..

Comment: I am getting error like LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. – Rahul Srivastava